# WAMP server not running after enabling httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: wamp, wampserver, httpd.conf

I tried enabling Virtual Host on my WAMP installation, but WAMP server will not run if I enable http-vhosts.conf, and the icon remains orange.

Here is my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       test.localhost
```

My httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/test"
    ServerName test.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

It works fine if I add the VirtualHosts to my httpd.conf, but I noticed that the Apache server will not run if I comment out "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf". What is causing this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: go to your apache folder, run httpd.exe from command line, it will show the error.

Comment: You may get better help on http://serverfault.com/ - This site is more geared toward the actual programming end of things.

Comment: Why are you commenting out the "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf", don't you want to uncomment it? Also, check you error log.

Answer (score 20):

To determine the exact line on which the error is occurring, take the following steps:

1. Go to start menu
2. type "cmd"
3. press enter
4. paste the following `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\httpd.exe`

> Note:  You may need to tweak the `apache2.2.22` portion of the path according your local version of Apache.

Answer (score 11):

OK I feel this my duty to put this...

I too went on a rampage of checking forms and doing things like

`Listen *:80` & `NameVirtualHost *:80` but found that this was not necessary, the default settings were fine for me.

the problem started when I tried to put in my vhost declaration

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot 'c:\wamp\www\media_weber_edu\public'
    ServerName media.weber.dev
    <Directory 'c:\wamp\www\media_weber_edu\public'>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
    <\Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

here lied the problem

`<\Directory>` vs `</Directory>`

A huge help to finding this was running `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\httpd.exe`

this gave me an error like this

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 469 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 42 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf: Expected </\\Directory> but saw </VirtualHost>
```

So this may not be the exact problem but I hope this will help those in the future. So take a deep breath... glue the hair back on your head... its going to be ok :)

Comment: Great tip on running httpd.exe!