# icon of wamp server do not turn to green

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, connection, wampserver

after i installed the wamp server it work fine but when i tried to create a virtual host it stop working and the icon just turn from red to orange and stop

these are the steps that i did to create a virtual host  if anything is wrong please tel me in which step

step 1

in the httpd.conf

```
<Directory "C:\wamp\www/">
    options Indexes followSymLinks--
    AllowOveride all--
    Order Deny.Allow--
    Deny from all--
    Allow from 127.0.0.1--
</Directory>
```

and uncomment the line that include **v-host** word

step 2.

add these lines to the httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admintestappdev.loc--
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/testappdev.loc"--
    ServerName testappdev.loc--
    ServerAlias www.testappdev.loc--
    ErrorLog "logs/testappdev.loc.error.log"--
    CustomLog "logs/testappdev.loc-access.log" Common--
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/"--
</VirtualHost>
```

step 3.

go to this path **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**

and add three line 
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 "name of the file"
127.0.0.1 "www. + nameof the file "

if anyone can help i will appreciate this

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247894/wamp-server-not-running-after-enabling-httpd-vhosts-conf/35430644#35430644](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247894/wamp-server-not-running-after-enabling-httpd-vhosts-conf/35430644#35430644)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by a lot of different things, here are a few checks.

1. Make sure apache2 configuration is valid (ie apache can read it properly)
2. (Obvious) Make sure port 80 is open and not being used by another program such as skype, apache provides a small command line program to check this. Click on the menu and navigate to the apache folder and there should be a menu item saying something along the lines of `Test Port 80`.
3. <strike>Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't know why you have loads of dashes on nearly every line? This will surely cause an error.</strike>

Wish I could be of more help but I'm running linux at the moment and don't use wamp server anymore. If you get really stuck reinstall wamp (backup databases etc first) and follow a tutorial online that works to get a working configuration.

See this answer [WAMP server not running after enabling httpd-vhosts.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247894/wamp-server-not-running-after-enabling-httpd-vhosts-conf) as it is very similar and could help you out.

Comment: the dashes are  just here just in my question to make space between lines i will delete it .. second my problem that i just need to create a virtual host to test my apps and i did follow some tutorials online  and what i did is one of these tutorials

Comment: Did you test port 80?

Comment: yesss i test it and it say that just the apache2.2 work on this port